# New VSTS build badge url behind auth no go for Github repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Not too long ago you could get a public build status badge url to display in a readme markdown file for things like Github.  Now the url provided in the UI Options pane is behind auth which is a no go for use in Github / external git repos.  I have two projects with build pipelines and the old public url for one of them works and using the same format and Project GUID for another one just indicates "Build pipeline X was not found".

I also had to install the VSTS cli just to get the Project GUID for the second project but the url doesn't work.

Anybody know how to get a valid public badge url that works and does not require auth?

Note: my repos are PRIVATE Github repos, not the built-in Git that VSTS provides.

URL for Build badge:

https://[vstsaccountname].visualstudio.com/_apis/public/build/definitions/[project_guid_that_is_hard_to_find]/[build_definition_number]/badge?api-version=4.1

Answer (score 0):

VSTS support Public and Private projects now. If you want a public build badge, you need to set the project to public. Refer to this link for details: [Make a private project public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/public/make-project-public?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#make-a-private-project-public).

Comment: It is private for a reason Eddie. I don't want to make the project public.